# prenex normal form and "free" variables

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$∀Y ((∀Xp(X, Y )) → ∃Zq(X, Z))$

I am trying to convert the above formula into prenex normal form. I have done the following, but my answer seems to slightly differ from the correct answer:

$∀Y ((\neg \forall X \; p(X, Y )) \lor ∃Z \;q(X, Z))$ (implication elimination)

$∀Y ((\exists X \; \neg p(X, Y )) \lor ∃Z \;q(X, Z))$ (Definition of $\exists$)

$∀Y\exists X  ((\neg p(X, Y )) \lor ∃Z \;q(X, Z))$ (Pull the existential $X$ quantifier out)

$∀Y\exists X\exists Z  ((\neg p(X, Y )) \lor q(X, Z))$ (Pull the existential $Z$ quantifier out)

However, the answer is: $∀Y ∃T∃Z(¬p(T, Y ) ∨ q(X, Z))$

Now I suspect it might be something to do with free variables, but I don't exactly know what I've done wrong. How come the $X$ turns into a $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $X$ in the consequent $\exists Z\,q(X,Z)$ is free. The $X$ quantifier in the antecedent $\forall X\,p(X,Y)$ does not bind it. That free $X$ has *nothing to do with* the bound $X$ in $\forall X\,p(X,Y)$. It's just a coincidence (an unfortunate one) that they're the same variable.
However, in your third step, you move $\exists X$ to the outside without changing it to a fresh variable. In doing that, you capture the $X$ that's free in $\exists Z\,q(X,Z)$. This changes the meaning of the formula, and the resulting formula is not logically equivalent to previous formula.

Another approach would be to change the free variable $X$ in the consequent to another, new variable before moving the $\exists X$ quantifier to outer scope, in order to not capture the free $X$ in $\exists Z\,q(X,Z)$. That would result in, for example,
$$\forall Y\,(\forall X\,p(X,Y) \to \exists Z\,q(S,Z))
$$
One or the other occurrence of $X$ has to be changed to a fresh variable, otherwise you change the meaning of the formula and don't preserve logical equivalence when moving quantifiers.

Comment: How can you tell if something is bound by a quantifier or not?

Comment: Your logic text surely explains this, in all the necessary detail. Briefly, every quantifier applies to a subformula of a formula, and binds all occurrences of its variable that are free in the subformula, *and only* those occurrences of the variable. There is no $X$ quantifier binding the $X$ in $\exists Z\,q(X,Z)$.

Comment: Right, so the placement of the parentheses also give an idea as to what quantifier binds what? In this case, the $X$ quantifier is in the scope of the parentheses in the left sub-expression and those do not extend to the right sub-expression.

Comment: True. But you could get rid of the parentheses around the subformula $\forall X p(X,Y)$ and that **still** would be true: this quantifier can't capture anything in the subformula to the right! The subformulas on the left and right of $\to$ are siblings, neither contains the other, quantifiers in one have nothing to do with quantifiers in the other and their variables can be changed to fresh variables without changing meaning.

Comment: Thank you, your answers are always great and clear! Keep it up.

Comment: Much obliged :) and thank you. I'm glad I could clarify this for you, because it can be tricky. It's hard to come up with natural language analogies to free variables. Bound variables and names, sure: *someone*, *everyone*, *Fido*, etc.

Comment: Also, a similar question. If I have a quantifier such as $\neg \forall X p(X,X)$, does the negation move with the quantifier or would it be legal to leave the negation as is and just move the $\forall$ quantifier out? I know it's quite a vague and general question but I don't have a concrete example

Comment: Consider the expression in my above comment to just be a snippet of a larger one otherwise it's already in prenex form

Comment: Well, the quantifier isn't moving anywhere until the negation moves past it and to the *right*, giving $\exists X\,\neg p(X,X)$. THAT is in prenex form; with the $\neg$ in front, it was not.